# New to nested loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am having an issue that, if the user inputs `Y` to get another set, the counts keep adding on instead of resetting in the output.

Outside the for loop, the total count for the current set should be printed out, but once I go on to more sets, the totals become a running total of all the sets, and not an individual count for the sets

So my question is that, is there a way to "reset" the count to zero without having to assign them to `0` again.

Also, I am having an issue where I can't get the set count to update either, I've tried putting it in the loops but nothing happened.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
const int UPPER_VALUE = 100;
const int LOWER_VALUE = 50;
const int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = 10;

int main()
{
 srand(time(0));    
 char userChoice = 'y';
 int less60Count = 0,
  in60Count = 0,
  in70Count = 0,
  in80Count = 0,
  above90Count = 0,
  i = 0,
  randomNum = 0,
  setCount = 1;

 while(tolower(userChoice) == 'y')
 {
  cout << "Set " << setCount << endl;
  for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
  {
   randomNum = LOWER_VALUE + ( rand() %  (UPPER_VALUE - LOWER_VALUE +1));
   if(randomNum < 60)
    less60Count++;
   else if(randomNum < 70)
    in60Count++;
   else if(randomNum < 80)
    in70Count++;
   else if(randomNum < 90)
    in80Count++;
   else
    above90Count++; 

  cout << randomNum << endl;
 }  
 setCount++;
 cout << "\n90s + count: " << above90Count << "  "
  << "80s count: " << in80Count << "  "
  << "70s count: " << in70Count << "  "
  << "60s count: " << in60Count << "  "
  << "Less than 60s: " << less60Count << endl << endl;
 cout << "Another one? ";
 cin >> userChoice;
 if(tolower(userChoice == 'n'))
  cout << "GoodBye!" << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with proper indentation of your source code.

Comment: 1. We have no line numbers, so please name what you want to reset. 2. You set your "count"-variables to 0 at the program start and nowhere else. If you want to reset them anywhere, you should probably do so...

Comment: Okay, my bad, I meant in the cout statement where I display the total number of the counts (outside the for loop, I'll fix that in the original question). As in, is there a way to "reset" them without having to set them to zero again?

Comment: And why would you not want to set them to zero again?

Comment: I originally had them just set to zero again after they were displayed, but I was told that it was not necessary to re set them to zero again, that I was wasting lines.
Also, what do you mean when you say proper indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the counters to the `while scope`, they will be set to 0 on each iteration.

```
int i = 0, randomNum = 0, setCount = 1;

while (tolower(userChoice) == 'y')
{
    int less60Count = 0,
        in60Count = 0,
        in70Count = 0,
        in80Count = 0,
        above90Count = 0;
}
```

Or just set them to 0 manually.

```
if (tolower(userChoice) == 'n')
    cout << "GoodBye!" << endl;
else
{
    less60Count = 0,
    in60Count = 0,
    in70Count = 0,
    in80Count = 0,
    above90Count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I originally had done the second option but I was told not to do that for whatever reason. I'm guessing since I had already declared them before the loops and re-declaring them was a "waste of lines"

Comment: @kenny10009 Found a typo in your code if(tolower(userChoice == 'n')) should if(tolower(userChoice) == 'n')